Duplicate Row Issue in UI with React Final Form and React final form arrays
I'm experiencing a strange issue with a project where I'm using react-final-form with react-beautiful-dnd for drag-and-drop functionality. The problem is that the UI is duplicating the last row, even though the object state is correct.
Here's a link to the sandbox demonstrating the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-final-form-field-arrays-react-beatiful-dnd-as-drag-drop-forked-7v6gst
